# How to implement SSO (single-sign-on) with third party CAS (Central Authentication Service) for a Django-React application?

Tags: django, reactjs, jwt, single-sign-on, cas

I'm setting up a Django-React application, with authentication through third party CAS. The process of CAS authentication looks like following:

1. The web application redirects the user's browser to CAS's login URL with a "service" parameter, for instance `https://cas.com/login?service=http://myapp.com`.
2. Once the user has been authenticated by CAS, CAS redirects the authenticated user back to the application, and it will append a parameter named "ticket" to the redirected URL. Its ticket value is the one-time identification of a "service ticket". For instance, `http://myapp.com/?ticket=abcdefg`.
3. The application can then connect to the CAS "serviceValidate" endpoint to validate the one-time service ticket. For instance, `https://cas.com/serviceValidate?service=http://myapp.com&ticket=abcdefg`.
4. In response, CAS shall return an XML containing the authenticated user id, for instance,

```
<cas:serviceResponse>
<cas:authenticationSuccess>
<cas:user>johnd</cas:user>
</cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

I've done some research and found it could be implemented in mainly two ways:

1. Serve react as part of Django's static content.
2. Standalone react single page application(SPA) through JWT.

I've tried the first approach and it works, but the problem is that every time I want to test the authentication with React, I need to build the static file first and put them in Django, which is kind of slow. So I would like to try the second approach.

My question is that is there any best practice I could implement for the standalone approach? If I were to implement JWT, is it safe to store the access token in `localStorage` or `cookie`?

Many Thanks!